# Unable to deserialize alternate name with GSON, AutoValue, and Retrofit 2

Tags: java, gson, retrofit2, auto-value

I am using retrofit version 2.1.0 to deserialize JSON into pojos. A field in the pojo can be received under different names in the json. To deserialize the field correctly, I used the @serializedName annotation in the following way:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Media implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName(value = "title", alternate = {"name"})
    public abstract String title();

// More fields and code
```

However, for some reason, when the resulting JSON has the field under the key "title", Gson reads it correctly, but when the field is associated with the "name" key, it does not get read.

How can I get GSON to recognize the alternate name during deserialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the `com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson` plugin.  Support for alternate serialized names was not [added](https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) until version 0.4.0.  Update to `com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.2` and you should then be able to deserialize alternate names.

Answer (score -1):

Seem the problem is related to Parcel.
You might want take a look at this 
[parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler)

```
@AutoValue
@Parcel
public abstract class Media {
    @ParcelProperty("title") public abstract String title();

}
```